# How to kill specific task on windows

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, tasks

There is two visual studio solutions opened, both have discreete names but under the umbrella of Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 name.
How can I specifically close one, without closing another?

Using TASKKILL /fi "IMAGENAME eq win32*" produce no result.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to kill a Visual Studio instance using a cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you want to do it on the basis of Solution opened, which is usually the title of window:

```
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq win32*"
```

For more filter options check taskkill help.

To see all values check:

```
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq win32*" /v
```